# How to speed up foreach loop for IEnumerator

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable, ienumerator

Little background

I am trying to use Intersystems IRIS Api
In case you want to see it.
https://docs.intersystems.com/irislatest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=BNETNAT_refapi#BNETNAT_refapi_iris-iterator

So basically I have  something like this (not the actual code)

```
string global = "myGlobal";
object subs = new object[2];
subs[0]="node1";
subs[1]="node2";
IRISIterator iter = iris.GetIRISIterator(global, subs); //Returns IEnumerator 

foreach(var item in iter)
{
       //for simplicity just printing it, actual code will process the data
            Console.WriteLine(iter.CurrentSubscript.ToString());
}
```

It runs very slow, it takes almost 4 seconds to read 50 records.
So my question is that given I do not have any control on GetIRISIterator, is it even possible to improve the performance of the above code?
Can I do some type of parallel processing or asynchronous execution to reduce the time?

Comment: That depends on which part takes a long time. If the enumerator is just _really slow_ at moving to the next record then there's little you can do. If it's the reference to `CurrentSubscript` that takes a long time to resolve, then you might be able to speed it up with concurrent/parallel processing.

Comment: Enumerator itself is slow at moving to the next record. I removed the reference to CurrentSubscript and it is take 3.4 seconds to finish  all the iterations.

Comment: How does this change as you add more records to the iterator? Are we sure it's moving to the next record that is slow, or is it perhaps establishing the initial result set that's taking the time? (Remember: with iterator blocks and lazy-evaluation of enumerables, it might not start processing the request at all until you enter the loop to request the first result).

Comment: So if I run the same code for 15 records it takes close to 1 second. so It is definitely moving to the next which is adding time. More records more time.

Comment: What are you intending to do with the retrieved values instead of Console.WriteLine in the actual application?
If the actual consuming operation also takes a bit of time, you could load the next value of the iterator in parallel to that operation. You might also take the first value and buffer the rest to a list. However, I don't think you will be able to decrease the total time this takes, you could just be doing something useful in parallel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible that the iterator does some slow operation each time the `.MoveNext()` method is called to advance to the next item. This may be caused by overhead accessing some external system, like a database, and it is possible this overhead is incurred for each item.

So the first thing I would attempt is to not use `GetIRISIterator`, there seem to be a `GetIRISList` that instead returns a list. It is possible that this only suffers the overhead once for the complete list.

Parallel processing is unlikely to improve anything, since it is the fetching of items that takes time, not the processing of items.

Asynchronous execution will not reduce the time taken, but it might improve user experience by showing the user that the system is working at processing the request and has not just hanged.

As whenever performance is discussed I will recommend doing appropriate measurements. Using a performance profiler might be very helpful since that may inform you where most of this time is spent.